# Htaccess - Reescrever URL com .htaccess dentro de um subdiretório

Tags: php, htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Estou tentando reescrever uma URL sendo que o arquivo .htaccess está dentro de um subdiretório.

URL atual: localhost/Desenvolvimento/Projetos/redirect/index.php

URL que eu gostaria de utilizar: localhost/redirect/index.php

A minha intenção é esconder o caminho até meu index.php, não mostrando que minha estrutura contém 'Desenvolvimento/Projetos'. Além disso, utilizar o arquivo .htaccess dentro da pasta redirect, pois pretendo utilizar um htaccess por projeto.

Htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^redirect/ ../../../index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Estrutura:

- htdocs (root)

  - index.html
  - Desenvolvimento

    - Projetos

      - redirect

        - index.php
        - .htaccess

Answer (score -1):

Para que seu htaccess consiga fazer isso ele vai precisar estar na pasta "htdocs";

Dentro do htaccess coloque o seguinte código:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^redirect/$ Desenvolvimento/Projetos/redirect/ [QSA,L,NC]
```